# Binding dates to SQL in Python for cx_Oracle

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using the following query to select logs fro a logs table.

```
SELECT * FROM LOGS  WHERE LOG_DATE BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP(:date_start, 'MM-DD-YYYY') AND TO_TIMESTAMP(:date_end, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

I have the following dictionary of parameters:

```
{'date_start': '02-24-20', 'date_end': '02-24-20'}
```

and executing the query as follows :

```
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

Now the problem is I am not getting any values for this date range. But if I execute the query in Oracle, by specifying the dates, it is working. What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specified format mask as `'MM-DD-YYYY'`, why do you then provide only two digits for year (`'02-24-20'`)? Provide 4 digits.